# PLY lex yacc: Errors handling

Tags: python, yacc, lex, ply

I am using PLY to parse a file. I have to print a message to the user when I have an error on a line.

A message like `Error at the line 4`.

```
def p_error(p):
    flag_for_error = 1
    print ("Erreur de syntaxe sur la ligne %d" % (p.lineno))
    yacc.errok()
```

But it is not working. I have the error

```
print ("Erreur de syntaxe sur la ligne %d" % (p.lineno))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lineno'
```

Is there another is more suitable way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem a while ago. It is caused by **unexpected end of input**.

Just test if `p` (which is actually a token in `p_error`) is `None`.

**Your code would look something like this:**

```
def p_error(token):
    if token is not None:
        print ("Line %s, illegal token %s" % (token.lineno, token.value))
    else:
        print('Unexpected end of input')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dit so some days ago but it doesn't work. The parser execute the else statement indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem.
My problem was that I always reinitialise the parser.

```
def p_error(p):
    global flag_for_error
    flag_for_error = 1

    if p is not None:
        errors_list.append("Erreur de syntaxe à la ligne %s"%(p.lineno))
        yacc.errok()
    else:
        print("Unexpected end of input")
        yacc.errok()
```

The good function is

```
def p_error(p):
    global flag_for_error
    flag_for_error = 1

    if p is not None:
        errors_list.append("Erreur de syntaxe à la ligne %s"%(p.lineno))
        yacc.errok()
    else:
        print("Unexpected end of input")
```

When I have an expected end of input, I must not continue parsing.

Thanks